# Passing parameter to method gotten from another method?

Tags: java, parameters, long-integer

I am new to Java but I know this stuff I'm just having a seerious brain fart. Could you help me. I've been up for 24+ hours writing code and I'm all confused now. Here is the code in question:

```
    public long getTheLong() {
    Scanner scano = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("enter account number");
    acctNum = scano.nextLong();
    return acctNum;
}

public void searchById(long acctNum) {
// do something with acctNum
{
```

the first method returns `acctNum` that gotten by user input. I want to take whatever `acctNum` is now after `getTheLong()` method was invoked and pass that to the the following method `searchById(long acctNum)`. How can I do something like this? Thank you so much, I know it's stupid but I'm confused at this point.

Comment: Be sure to change the last curly bracket to '}'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your java file

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestProgram 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        long acctNum = getTheLong();
        searchById(acctNum);
    }

    public static long getTheLong() 
    {
        long acctNum = 0;
        Scanner scano = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("enter account number");
        acctNum = scano.nextLong();
        return acctNum;
    }

    public static void searchById(long acctNum) 
    {
        // do something with acctNum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void searchById() {
    long acctNum = getTheLong();
    // do something with acctNum
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long acctNum = getTheLong();
searchById(acctNum );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the return value of the one function as an arguement to the second as below.

```
searchById(getTheLong());
```

Answer (score 0):

hi place it before return statement
    searchById(scano.nextLong());
Thanks